# SQL Server -Copy Views from one db to multiple dbs with the same schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

How do I copy a view from one database to other databases with the same schema at the same time, I dont want to do the script process for each db, its very time consuming . I have atleast 5 other dbs that need these views ?

Comment: Please rephrase your "question." I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Yes go ahead and copy.. Answered to the point:)

Comment: How do I copy a view from one database to other databases with the same schema at the same time, I dont want to do the script process for each db, its very time consuming . I have atleast 5 other dbs that need these views ?

Comment: Which Version of SQL server are you using? And are you open to using SSIS?

Comment: Guess SSIS is a no-no too...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just script out the view as Create to New Query Editor Window, then change the USE DATABASENAME on top to your other databases, one at a time.  If your view contains fully qualified references (database.schema.object), you may have to do a find and replace on the database name.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your database in SSMS, Tasks -->  Generate Scripts and in Objects section just select the Views or any other objects you want to script and execute the script on your target servers/databases

[image]

When you say you dont want to script, its like saying I dont want to work but I still want to be able to pay my bills. If you dont want to script I dont think you have any other options available for you.

Comment: Please double check the question again